# Too many SPF lookups?

Tags: spf

How do I handle it if my hosting provider's default SPF record includes more IP lookups than are allowed by DMARC (maximum 10)?  Here's the default SPF record for rockridgencpc.com:

v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:35.208.189.85 include:_spf.mailspamprotection.com ~all

If you run that through the DMARC SPF checker you'll find that mailspamprotection.com has 3 MX servers but each MX server has 12 separate IP addresses.  This way overruns the maximum of 10 allowed "lookups."  My hosting provider says that's the default and so far won't discuss the fact that their default is in violation of an internet standard.  I've gotten the error from 2 different SPF checkers.  Since I set their default I haven't been able to send email through the forwarder addresses in our domain, although other people can.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses don't count towards the total because they don't require DNS lookups. From [RFC7208 section 4.6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.6.4):

> The other terms -- the "all", "ip4", and "ip6" mechanisms, and the
> "exp" modifier -- do not cause DNS queries at the time of SPF
> evaluation (the "exp" modifier only causes a lookup at a later time),
> and their use is not subject to this limit.

This is also why you should always put literal IP mechanisms first in your SPF as they are fastest for receivers to handle. Your entire set of targets can be resolved through 6 lookups, so I don't see any contravention here or why anything should be triggering errors from these records.

Comment: Synchro, I agree but it’s not always practical to go all IP in an SPF, but I like your idea in principle as it comes of as more more rational.

Comment: I never said it was, just that you should put the IPs first, not that you should use them *instead*. If you ignore the IPs (as they don't count towards the total), you do not get anywhere the SPF lookup limit in the records you've provided.

Comment: Ah, okay, makes sense now. Sorry for the misunderstanding. It’s been a longgg day already.

Answer (score 1):

The mx modifier makes your SPF do another round of DNS queries and it’s not necessary. Try removing the mx and then re validating and see if you’re under the 10 lookups.

If that does not work you could flatten your spf record. There are several tools for flattening records.

You could check your domain’s spf using then https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/ which will then show the spf flattened option if you go above the 10 lookups.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies, I now know more about SPF records!  Neil Anuskiewicz, your suggestion is EXACTLY what the tech support team at my hosting company did, once I sent them enough evidence to prove what was actually happening.  I'm currently waiting for the DNS changes to replicate across the Internet.  I did use the DMARC SPF survey tool, but if it suggested the flattened option I must not have understood what it meant.

Comment: If you use the SPF survey again and it's below 10 DNS lookups then you're good. If the domain still fails for too many lookups, you'll be able to scroll down to see "flattening" options. Flattening a record is kind of a pain so I'd say it's last resort.